# Does hibernate check length of column?

Tags: java, hibernate, size, hbmxml

I have only access to db and read-only access to hbm.xml files. It is need to increase column size. I see that in table/column definition in hbm.xml files for this table no attribute length. Should application work with increased column size in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it will. Hibernate doesn't care about the length of the columns.

Why don't you simply test it?

Answer (score 2):

Hibernate doesn't limit the length of it's attributes it's a limitation set at database level.

Normally DB will allocate enough length for the relevant fields.

Since you said you only have read access I don't think that it's relevant anyway...